# Views, Controllers, Models and Ajax, Any advice for building a tool that needs to auto update? (ASP.NET MVC Razor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hey guys I wanted to know if I get get some advice from some asp.NET MVC and Ajax users. I'm building a tool that allows you create a wishlist app and wanted to add ajax to it and make it more dynamic.

For example. Users can enter a shopping term, I will pull up a list of products(from various apis and web services) and then they add in a description(why they want it) and hit submit. I will add the item(custom class like WishListItem.vb) to the list(WishList.vb) and display the item and description on the page. They can keep doing this over and over.

But getting a postback every time is annoying and not very user friendly. So I wanted to add Ajax functionality to it. And wanted to know if you guys had some good ways with jQuery and straight Javascript to do it.

For example when the users type in want they want and it's description and hit submit. I will add it to their list via ajax. And update the content display said the list with ajax. Like it would show a progress bar and then display the list with the newly add item.

I see some Ajax.BeginForm() in the views, and wanted to get some guidance on the best way to implement this.

I was wondering how can I get my View to communicate with the Model, and vice versa which I know shouldn't happen. But how else would I add items to the list and update the html with Ajax?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery.ajax and a partial view.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    type: "POST",
    data: { Item: "SKU#???", Descr: "Some Description" },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#SomeElement").html(data);
    }
});
```

Then in the action, return a partial view of the result.